# editing text file in a telnet connection without text editor

Tags: linux, audio, putty

I need to modify a text file inside a wifi audio receiver that runs OpenWRT, and i've reached the file i need in /etc/config/audio , and i have editing rights (i'm rebooting the device in secure mode so i'm root), but the **darn** thing doesn't have a text editor, of all things! i've tried vi, vim, emacs, joe, nano, but doesn't seem to have any. it does have echo, cat, grep and a few more but none are text editors.

I'm logging into it with PuTTY, and any other connection besides Telnet is refused. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: (1) I suppose `sed` and `awk` are unlikely to be there, but have you checked for `ed` and `ex`?  (2) Can you download the file, edit it on your computer, and then upload it?  (If so, I suggest that you upload it with a different name, `diff` them to make sure nothing went wrong, and then either rename (`mv`) or copy (`cp`) the new file over the old file.)

Comment: there's ed but i don't know about ex or all the others. what i'm certain is that i don't know how to down/upload the file into/from my pc while telneting to the device within PuTTY.

Comment: Telnet isn't secure... So what is secure mode?

Comment: Sorry for wording it badly, i was talking about Failsafe mode https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe

Comment: and I know telnet is not secure but I can't use any other thing since the device rejects any other protocol i've tried in PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally fixed it!

the command i needed was a mix of sed and find, which I found in a website and i'll post here;

find etc/config/audio -type f -exec sed -i 's/OLDNAME/NEWNAME/g' {} \;

this edited the particular file and it searched and replaced OLDNAME (which i replaced with the current parameter that the variable had), and NEWNAME (with the one i wanted to give it) and this worked like a charm.

whew

Comment: I don't see why you would need to use `find`; if the command you posted works, then the direct invocation, `sed -i 's/OLDNAME/NEWNAME/g' /etc/config/audio/filename`, should work, too.  ... ... ... ... ... ... ...  P.S. I did mention `sed` in my first comment; I assumed that you had looked for it when you said "it does have ... a few more but none are text editors."

Comment: If this solved your problem, you may want to accept this answer which will indicate to the community that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ed`. 
Read the [GNU 'ed' Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) if you're not familiar with it
(although if you know the **`:`** commands in `vi`, you're halfway there).

Comment: I'm really sorry, couldn't check properly when i said that there was ed. No there isn't................ I wonder what else I can do. Thanks a lot for support